# Failure querying AWS Athena from DBeaver using IAM profiles / ephemeral credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, dbeaver, amazon-athena

When I try to configure DBeaver to query Athena, it does not work.  I get errors about loading a credentials provider class.

We use ephemeral credentials / IAM profiles in order to authenticate to everything.  So, I'm trying to leverage those and avoid insecure IAM users.  So, I'm not populating the user name or password.

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled across this GitHub and it worked like a charm: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/3918#issuecomment-511484596.

Here are the relevant notes (slightly modified for easier understanding):

1. Do your normal AWS login process to refresh your credentials (in our case, we use okta + gimme_aws_creds for this).
2. Go to driver properties on your DBeaver Athena connection and set:

   - `AwsCredentialsProviderClass` to `com.simba.athena.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider`
   - `AwsCredentialsProviderArguments` equal to the name of the profile you want to use (see ~/.aws/config to see which profiles you have) -- we use "default".
3. Test Connection and it should work.