# Profile file cannot be null error using DBeaver under Windows10 AWS Athena IAM profile

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-athena, dbeaver

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69991535/failure-querying-aws-athena-from-dbeaver-using-iam-profiles-ephemeral-credenti) and this [thread in GitHub](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/3918#issuecomment-511484596). It works for Mac but doesn't work for Windows.

And I still getting the error.

Looks like dbeaver doesn't have access to the credentials file.

Any ideas?
Below you may see my settings:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a file called `config` in the same `.aws` directory with the following structure:

```
[your_DataAccess_profile_name]
your-aws-region
```

Pay attention to file extensions, it should be:

`config` and
`credentials`

**not**

`config.txt` and `credentials.txt`

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: I've just noticed that your file is *.txt - I've updated my answer