# Can't create a connection to AWS Athena from DBeaver with an IAM profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, dbeaver

I'm trying to set up a connection from local DBeaver to Athena. Specifically, I have an IAM profile which I think is what makes my attempt unsuccessful.

I should mention first that I *am* successful in establishing a connection via an *R* package called [`noctua`](https://github.com/DyfanJones/noctua).

In *R*, the following **works**:

```r
# r
con <- DBI::dbConnect(noctua::athena(), 
                 profile_name = "default-prof", 
                 region = "us-east-1",
                 s3_staging_dir = "s3://s3.foo.bar.baz",
                 schema_name = "my_schema_name",
                 duration_seconds = 3600,
                 role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::123456789123:role/FooRole",
                 work_group = "my-workgroup-foo"
                 )
```

Note that `profile_name = "default-prof"` refers to the profile I set in my `config` & `credentials` on my local machine.

```bash
# config
[profile default-prof]
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

```bash
# credentials
[default-prof]
aws_access_key_id = ********
aws_secret_access_key = *******
```

By the way, those R parameters pretty much correspond to [`pyathena`](https://pypi.org/project/pyathena/) too.

---

### Why can't I use the same login procedure with DBeaver?

[image: main]

I also tried going by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69991536/6105259) advice:

> Go to driver properties on your DBeaver Athena connection and set:
>
> - AwsCredentialsProviderClass to  com.simba.athena.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider
> - AwsCredentialsProviderArguments equal to the name of the profile you want to use (see ~/.aws/config to see which profiles you have) -- we use "default".

but it didn't work.

I also tried to create a custom driver property for IAM, called it `role_arn`, and put `arn:aws:iam::123456789123:role/FooRole`, but didn't work. Tried naming it `preferred_role` but also didn't work.

Comment: "didn't work": any error message?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your current IAM as per `~/.aws/config` can assume the `arn:aws:iam::123456789123:role/FooRole`.

Also, in my DBeaver there's a dropdown to select credentials - use AWS IAM and then the profile name (`default`?) rather than username and password.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Which DBeaver instance do you have? I use the Community Edition.

Comment: The screenshot is from Beaver Lite, but I've set it up with CE as well... Don't you see the "AWS IAM" option in CE?

Comment: Nope, I get the screen as in the screenshot in the post.